# How do I fix npm run build generating a blank index.hml?

Tags: node.js

When I do `npm run build` the command prompt shows that it was successful:

[image]

However, a blank `index.html` is generated and the project does not get correctly built.
This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "linktree",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://alejandrolopez.org",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "node": "^14.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render( < React.StrictMode >
    <App/>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header'
import Card from './components/Card'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import items from './assets/items'

import './css/skeleton.css'
import './css/normalize.css'

function App() {
    return ( 
        <div className = "App" >
            <Header></Header>
            <div className = "container row">
                {
                    items.map((item, i) => {
                        return(
                            <Card
                            i={i}
                            title={item.title}
                            subtitle={item.subtitle}
                            link={item.link}
                            cover={item.image}>
                            </Card>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
            <Footer></Footer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

How can I build my app so that the `index.html` is not empty and it shows my app instead? When I do `npm start` my website shows up perfectly so why does it not show when I build it? I have been trying to fix this for hours, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting `homepage` to `.` in your `package.json` file:

```
"homepage": "."
```

see [this doc](http://%20https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).